# cats `Eq`'s `===` with Scalatest

Tags: scala, scala-cats

I was reading [*Scala with Cats*](https://underscore.io/blog/posts/2017/11/22/scala-with-cats.html) and in the first chapter of the book, they describe `Eq` usage.

One of the exercises is about writing an instance of that typeclass for validating the equality of two *cats*. Consider this:

**Model**

`final case class Cat(name: String, age: Int, color: String)`

**Typeclass instance**

```
import cats.Eq
import cats.syntax.eq._
import cats.instances.string._
import cats.instances.int._
import co.alejandrome.typeclass.model.Cat

object CatsEqInstances {

  implicit val catsEq: Eq[Cat] = Eq.instance[Cat] {
    (cata, catb) =>
      cata.color === catb.color && cata.age === catb.age && cata.name === catb.name
  }

}
```

**Unit tests**

```
import co.alejandrome.typeclass.model.Cat
import org.scalatest.{FlatSpec, Matchers}
import cats.instances.option._

class EqTest extends FlatSpec with Matchers{

  import CatsEqInstances._

  "Eq" should "compare two cats" in {
    val cat1 = Cat("Garfield",   38, "orange and black")
    val cat2 = Cat("Heathcliff", 33, "orange and black")

    catsEq.eqv(cat1, cat2) shouldBe false

    val cat3 = Cat("Garfield",   38, "orange and black")

    catsEq.eqv(cat1, cat3) shouldBe true
  }

  it should "compare two Optional cats" in {
    val cat1 = Cat("Garfield",   38, "orange and black")
    //val cat2 = Cat("Heathcliff", 33, "orange and black")

    val optionCat1 = Option(cat1)
    val optionCat2 = Option.empty[Cat]

    optionCat1 === optionCat2
  }

}
```

The first test works fine, but the second one doesn't because `===` operator is the Scalatest one, not the `Eq` one.

I explored if the typeclass has any syntax or implicit for this but I cannot find anything about it. I saw in [this PR](https://github.com/typelevel/cats/pull/522) that there's a solution for this, based on [Bill Venner's solution](https://github.com/bvenners/equality-integration-demo), but this is only for cats own unit tests.

I was poking with `EqSyntax` trait but I can't figure it out how to *override* scalatest own implementation of `===`.

Is there any way to do this? Or is this not implemented yet?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understand your problem correctly, but it looks like you can re-use what Cats implemented for their own tests basing on the PR you referenced. Just change your test class definition to

```
class EqTest extends FlatSpec with Matchers with cats.tests.StrictCatsEquality  {
```

and then you can write tests such as

```
optionCat1 === optionCat2 shouldBe false
```

or

```
optionCat1 should !== (optionCat2)
```

and they will you use your `Eq[Cat]` definition (if it is imported into the scope).

Essentially the idea is that ScalaTest `===` uses some implicit such as `CanEqual`. So if you provide (import) your custom implicit implementation - you can change how `===` works inside.

Comment: That's what I wanted! I've looked at that class (`StrictCatsEquality`) but I thought that it wasn't visible. Looks like this could be a future feature of cats (provide some kind of implicit/trait for overriding this behavior with Scalatest), because, although this works, it seems to me that the referenced class is more for cats' own use.